# Retrieving select options with $.post()

Tags: jquery

Which is the preferable method of populating a `<select>` dropdown through one of jQuery's `$.ajax()` methods? Is there is a significant performance benefit with either method?

1. Return the new `<option>`s as JSON and use `$.each()` to add them as `<options>` to a string, and then use `$.html()` to populate the `<select>`
2. Generate the HTML on the server side in the AJAX script, and just `$.load()` the HTML into the `<select>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the fastest way i the append function : http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 0):

First way is better, since JSON consumes quite less network traffic than HTML markup and generating markup on client side will take the extra work from server.